# Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.5 0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

good day, I was about to deploy my app as APK. everything is okay as I run a debug to my phone. And I was ready to build it as an APK. and this happened. This error keeps showing up and I have no idea what to do.

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.5  0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Also tried to run it on my phone and this happened

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH1803 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom
       - http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.5  0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.pom
       - http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried several methods but non works. I don't know what to do.

PS, please make it easier to explain because I don't know such in this problem. If possible, please make it a step by step for dummies like me thank you. I really need your help. Please!!! Thank you

Update> This is the new error in app\build.gradle

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.5  0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.5  0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.5  0.pom
Required by:
    project :
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `you are not connected to internet`.
Flutter is unable to download the required dependencies.
Please connect to internet for your first build using a new library and run `flutter pub get` and then `flutter run` again once.

Let me know if it works .

Comment: I am connected to the internet but let me do this first

Comment: ok. after trying let me know if its working.

Comment: If it doesnt works so .just do this. goto ```your project folder/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties``` and change distributionUrl to ```https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip```

Comment: It still has the error also I have an error in build.gradle that says "Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'."            here is the code:

Comment: Try ```flutter create .``` it will re-initialize the project without affecting the source. You may have messed with something... also remove everything except ```lib``` folder and then run that command

Comment: im sorry i am new to this. this might be a stupid question but please bear with me. How do you try flutter create? where will I put it? please elaborate more. Sorry

Comment: I assume you are using windows and have done flutter setup properly. So go to your project folder . in address bar type ```powershell``` . in there type ```flutter create . ``` before that make sure to delete everything in your project folder except the ```lib``` folder.

Comment: I deleted everything except lib and when I do lib is also deleted I dont know why

Comment: copy it somewhere else and run that command there .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232556/discussion-between-prashanthth-kumar-and-john-ryle-singh).